# Can 'show mac address-table' be used inside user mode?

Tags: cisco, ios

I've been studying for my CCNA exams using *Cisco ICND1 Official Cert Guide,  Wendell Odom*. On one question they ask in which modes `show mac address-table` can be executed. The answer is *User mode* and *Enable mode*, so they say. I haven't been able to execute that command under user mode, neither in packet tracer nor my C3500XL switch.

Can `show mac address-table` be used inside user mode?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about homework.

Comment: It might be off-topic but not due to homework, unless you include self study into your 'homework' definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the list of show commands available in each mode you'll get your answer.

`sh mac-address-table` is only available in privileged exec (enable) mode on the C3500XL.

Comment: I am not to certain about that. For relatively young switches this is correct, but I distinctly remember some old stuff (1900 series maybe, can't recall) that allowed this in non-privileged mode. Having said that, anyone who still runs those, should have his head examined...

Comment: Yep. I just looked at a 2950 and sh mac-address-table is available in User Exec mode, so it appears the answer is specific to the device/IOS version. The key is to run sh ? in both modes and see what commands are available in each.

Comment: A 2950 isn't even that old. I've still got several in use (albeit in a non-critical environment). Anyway I can't really think of any reason why it would be restricted to exec-mode. It is about on the same level as "show int", "show cdp" and "show vlan" and these are also available in non-exec.